# Editing the user dashboard existing pages without changing the core template file

Tags: magento-1.7, template

How to edit a existing page of user dashboard in magento without changing the core template file. I want to add few more information on "My Account page" which is the home page of the user dashboard, if the user is a business user. I want to add one more block below the user information.

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main block holding the 'widgets' in the customer account section is `customer_account_board`, so if you want to add a block there you would have to reference that one

```
<customer_account_index>
    <reference name="customer_account_dashboard">
        [...]
    </reference>
</customer_account_index>
```

Build this would require you to edit `frontend/base/default/template/customer/account/dashboard.phtml` to add a `getChildHtml` for your section.

To not be required to edit the file you could add your block under reference name `content` , under this reference all blocks will be included automatically.

```
<customer_account_index>
    <reference name="conten">
        <block type="your/block" name="your_block" after="customer_account_dashboard" template="your/block.phtml"/>
    </reference>
</customer_account_index>
```

Comment: Thank you very much... magento is having very nice features...i am new in magento.. may I add you in any social sites like facebook or tweeter?? Once again thank you very much...

Comment: You can find me on twitter although I don't tweet that much about Magento. Take a look at @philwinkle's mageoverflow list for some nice references https://twitter.com/philwinkle/lists/mageoverflow-com

Comment: thanks :) .. I just wanted to be in touch with you. I am so new in programming :)

Comment: Ah no problem, you can find me by name